# why signalr can't run websocket on linux(with mono),super diff.ult..qeus-tion.(may mono's bug)

Tags: linux, websocket, mono, signalr-2

someone said:
it is not working as System.Web.WebSocket is not implemented in the Mono and they are not planing to implement it this days.
but mono has already implemented System.Web.WebSocket .
I think there is something wrong with mono's code ,But I dont know?
anyone else know this?

Comment: http://sta.github.io/websocket-sharp/

Comment: Here a sample SignalR on .NET Core with WebSockets https://github.com/bertt/SignalR.Core.Sample